# Excel: How to internally store a numerical value in a cell but make it appear differently (Ex. Alphabetical Names)?

Tags: microsoft-excel

For example, I want to name a cell "Win (+5)", but I want it to act like it just has "5" in it so I can use it for functions and etc,.

I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Comment: do you mean you want the contents of the cell to be "Win (+5)" and you want to be able to extract the +5 value?  ("naming" a cell is something different)

Comment: That is a way around, and I actually just ended up making a vb function that does that. But I'm still wondering if there's an easier way because now if I want to sum multiple cells of "Win (+5)" and others, I have to do SUM(ExtractNumber(B4)+ExtractNumber(C4)+ ... which becomes way too long.

Comment: Yea....you appear to be doing as I thought... the simplest way I can think to do this is to use a helper column with a formula that finds the char position of `(` and `)` and extracts the value between them. I can cook up such a formula if you need it.

Comment: @Tyson That's a way too! Don't bother though, I think I should stop being so lazy haha. Still thanks though!

Comment: here ya go anyway: `=VALUE(MID(B2,FIND("(",B2)+1,FIND(")",B2)-FIND("(",B2)-1))` that will take whatever's in B2 and exact the value between the `(` and `)`.   Copy it down the column then add a sum at the bottom.

Comment: Another option (if the text part is consistent is to have the value 5 in the cell and just use a custom format like "WIN (+"0")"

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is the **custom number format**. You will use the cell exactly the same way you do with any cell; it will only be visually different.

1. Add the value to the cell (5 in your example).
2. Go to Home -> Number format -> More number formats.
3. On the new window, select Category: Custom
4. On the field type, add "WIN (+"0")";"WIN (-"0")"; "WIN ("0")"

[image]

The three codes represent the format you want for positive numbers, negative numbers, and for zero. See that you should include the external brackets on step 4.

**Final result**

[image]

Comment: Please share some screen shot,, because if in a cell value is `Win (+5)` and applied custom format `"WIN (+"0")"` the value remain as Win (+5)` and if use the cell for any formula u get #VALIUE error,,, Excel not considers it as +5 or 5 !! And what about US (-6) ?

Comment: **Cont,,** the formula suggested by @Tyson is correct way to handle such data !! Or U may use =SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,7,2),")","")  for Win (+5).

Comment: @RajeshS, I edited my answer. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: The solution does what is stated in the question: "store a numerical value in a cell but make it appear differently".  Please let me know if you have any questions or suggestions for me to improve the answer.

Comment: now the edited part is more clear and louder too,,, but this is never a good thought  since is for a particular patters only,,, limits the scope of the formatting.