# Excel formulas for stripping out prefix/suffix around number

Tags: microsoft-excel

The other day I had some timesheet information in a spreadsheet ($X/hr, Y hrs), and I wanted to compute dollars spent.  I wound up just editing out the "/hr", " hrs" and "$" characters, but is there a way I could have converted these cells directly to floats in the formula to perform the calculation?

=B$3 * B$4

I tried VALUE and it didn't work.

Comment: I answered something similar here: http://superuser.com/questions/794199/excel-how-to-internally-store-a-numerical-value-in-a-cell-but-make-it-appear-di Read the comments. If you would like help with formulas that work for your data let me know...

Comment: Find and replace the "/hr" string and "hrs" with nothing "" using the Find replace dialog box in excel. In the title column  of the time sheet add the units. For example "Rate ($/hr)" and "Time (hrs)". Now they are just mere numbers in that column. U can use simple * to do the job. This is how we do timesheets in my office.

Comment: @Prasanna That was what I did - but I was hoping to find a programmatic way to do this.  The answer below was more what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this small **UDF**

```
Public Function NumberPart(s As String) As Double
    Dim s2 As String, i As Long, L As Long, CH As String
    s2 = ""
    L = Len(s)
    For i = 1 To L
        CH = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If CH Like "[0-9]" Or CH = "." Then
            s2 = s2 & CH
        End If
    Next i
    NumberPart = CDbl(s2)
End Function
```

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as **.xlsm** rather than **.xlsx**

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=NumberPart(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

for specifics on UDFs

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: To learn more about using VBA in Microsoft Office in general, see [How do I add VBA in MS Office?](http://superuser.com/q/801609/354511)

Answer (score 1):

Although the above answer works and very well documented, I have two objections against it:

- It gives false output if the input contains unintended numerical values (for example, try: "12 hrs1" or "$ 12 / 1 hr" or when your locale uses "," as a decimal separator instead of ".").
- If possible I'd stay away from Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) and UDF's; especially if the same can be achieved with the following native Excel functions:

  - `LEFT`: takes the left side of a string up to a certain length (used to cut the "/hr" off).
  - `VALUE`: converts a tekst to a value (used to convert the remaining value in a string to a value).
  - `FIND`: searches for a character or string in another string (used to search for '/' in "/hr").
  - `SUBSTITUTE`: changes all occurrences of a string in another string (used to remove the "HRS").
  - `UPPER`: converts all characters to uppercase (used to change "Hrs" and "hrs" etc. to "HRS").

If the mentioned values are in column A (price per hour) and B (amount of hours), starting with data at row 1 (no header row) then put the following formula's in Excel:

- C1: `=VALUE(LEFT(A2;FIND("/";A1;1)-1))` and copy-paste down as needed.
- D1: `=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(B1);"HRS";""))`  and copy-paste down as needed.

That should do the trick. Nothing too complex I'd say.

Comment: Good ideas___________another approach is to put the *units* in the formatting and avoid the numerical problems entirely!

Comment: Agree, but that's not an answer to the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to use VBA together with Regex and a [fitting pattern](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/).
For example, the `\D` pattern matches everything which isn't a digit (0-9).

1. Insert this code into a VBA **module** (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>). The UDF needs 2 arguments when called from Excel: The input cell and the RegEx pattern to check against. Then, the code removes every character which matches the given pattern.

   ```
   Function Remove(objCell As Range, strPattern As String)

       Dim RegEx As Object
       Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
       RegEx.Global = True
       RegEx.Pattern = strPattern
       Remove = RegEx.Replace(objCell.Value, "")

   End Function
   ```
2. Back in Excel write your formula in this syntax to a new cell

   ```
   =Remove( <cellToCheck> ,"<regExPattern>")
   ```

I've taken your example to multiply two "non-digit" cells: `$50/hr * 8 hrs = 400`

[image]

---

However, this won't work if you have multiple (unintended) numerical values in one cell e.g `$50/hr2`